# Approved/OK form of cross posting

Tags: support, questions, exact-duplicates

Let us say I have (and I have!) a very technical question related to the (proper) mathematical formulation of physical theories. Should I ask it in one section only (let's say mathematics) and wait for a good/thorough answer there, or should I cross-post it in the physics section, knowing that the mathematically qualified members of the physics section won't really visit the mathematics section to get the chance to see it and answer to it?

What is the right solution for me to ensure greatest chances of receiving a well-formulated answer?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7122/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7413/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the same core question that you want to ask to two different communities and you really are looking for different input from the two, then it's quite likely that the posts will end up looking rather different. In that case, it's OK to post simultaneously in the two sites, but it is crucial that you mention that fact in both versions and provide cross-post links on both.

On the other hand, it can happen that the versions you want to ask on the two sites will be essentially identical, in which case it's not really considered OK to cross-post simultaneously on both. Choose the one you think is best and post there, and wait to see what the response is. If after several days you feel that it's not really what you were hoping for, it's OK to cross-post ─ again, with explicit markers of that fact and the respective links in both versions.

Comment: No, I am not looking for different content from two different communities. The answer I am looking for should be essentially unique since I am interested in the mathematical content. At most, it should be different ways to mathematically prove the same result. Alright, here's what I will do: I will post it/them in the physics.SE, then wait for a week. If I cannot obtain the answer I am looking for, then I will re-post it under the math.SE with cross-links in both posts.

Comment: @DanielC I could add that you don't necessarily need to cross-post - if you really just want the same question on math.SE, then after the week or so in which it hasn't been answered here, we could simply migrate it over to math.SE (with all potentially helpful comments). If you wish to do that, just raise a custom moderator flag asking us to migrate the question.

Comment: Thank you, that's even better.